# XML string validation against XSD in Angular

Tags: angular, xsd-validation, xml-validation, client-side-validation

I want to validate a XML string user provides as an Input against XSD. I found solutions for backend but don't see any client-side solution. Any suggestions?

Simple XML string validation is possible that checks syntax errors, But I am looking for validation against XSD.